# Should we close questions that can be easily solved by reading the subject's Wikipedia page?

Tags: discussion

I just saw [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/55220/how-was-suspicion-1941-supposed-to-end) and quite frankly I want to close it, because it can be answered by simply visiting the movie's Wikipedia page. But there isn't a close reason for "lack of research", unfortunately.

Sure, I can downvote it. But chances are some others will upvote it (people even upvote blatantly off-topic questions), and thus this low-quality question will live on. (Right now it already has two upvotes and one person has "starred" the question.)

Back in 2011 it seems there was [a process to close such questions](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19/should-we-outrule-questions-without-research-effort), and if I google ["hitchcock suspicion original ending"](https://www.google.com/search?q=hitchcock%20suspicion%20original%20ending) the first link is the Wikipedia entry and the excerpt hints at the answer:

> Suspicion (1941) is a romantic psychological thriller directed by
>   Alfred Hitchcock, and starring .... **Hitchcock's recollection of this
>   original ending—in his book-length interview with François Truffaut,
>   published in English as Hitchcock/Truffaut in** ...

And this isn't the only question like that, I've seen plenty recently.

Comment: Duplicate,  [How to handle low quality “plot-explanation” questions](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2113/how-to-handle-low-quality-plot-explanation-questions)

Comment: Um, but you do know that "starring" a question does come with absolutely *zero* notion of preferring it in anyway, do you? I favourite tons of low-quality questions on a daily basis. And now that this meta question is asked, I have to star it anyway.

Comment: There are tones of questions here that can be answered using the most basic Google search. I've always seen that as a normal situation.

Answer (score 8):

Lack of research really isn't a close reason... it's a downvote reason.

When you hover over the downvote button, you'll see that the text reads:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

All three of those are reasons to downvote.

By contrast, none of our close reasons are "does not show research".

Some sites do have a "does not show research" close reason as one of their custom off-topic reasons but I don't think it's really necessary here.

Yes, we're not going to answer trivial questions like "who starred in ___" because that's something that Wikipedia or IMDb can answer but, as in that post from 2011, if the answer is interesting... which I think the answer to that *Suspicion* question would count as "interesting"... the guidance is to "answer the question".

[image: When to answer simple questions]

If you don't think it's interesting, let someone else answer.

Comment: According to the most recent community consensus and policy on the same topic, **trivia / general reference questions are *no longer considered off-topic* by the community**:  [Which trivia questions are on-topic and which are off-topic?](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4874/1006) and [We're retiring the "trivia" close-reason](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4901/1006).